# Sum one column to multiple columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, sum

I ran into a very odd error today. I am trying to add the values of one column to multiple columns but pandas is throwing a memory error. I looked around but I must be wording the problem poorly because I found a bunch of `pd.concat` questions.

Imagine the following data frame:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({c1:[100,200,300],c2:[10,20,30],c3:[1,2,3]})
```

I want to reassign columns `c1` and `c2` so that they become their original values plus `c3`. I thought this would work:

```
df[['c1','c2']] = df[['c1','c2']] + df['c3']

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError
```

I solved it doing the following, but there has to be a better solution.

```
df[['c1','c2']].apply(lambda x: x + df['c3'])
```

What am I missing? Is there a way to use an `axis` argument to make the first method work? Is there a way to use `.sum()` to achieve this?

Comment: You need to specify the axis when adding a Series to a DataFrame: `df[['c1','c2']].add(df['c3'], axis=0)`

Comment: I had never used `.add`. I thought `.sum` could be used for cases like this. Do you want to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ALollz posted the solution as a comment, so here it is as an answer. Hope it helps someone in the future:

```py
df[['c1','c2']] = df[['c1','c2']].add(df['c3'], axis=0)
```

I was not specifying the axis argument, hence the importance of `.add()`.